# Rating rows by conditions

Tags: hive, hiveql

[The existing Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6957a.png)

Hello guys,
The existing dataset:

```
Student_id  Book_id class_id    timestamp
1101        NV5602  12          null
1101        NV5401  31          11/09/2021 16:50
1101        NV5401  12          null
```

I have book_id consisting of 2 letters at first and numbers afterward. I would like to pick for each Student_id the highest book_id number (NV5602 - in the example above).

If there is 2 book_id with the same number (in our example: NV5401) for the same student_id then rate the row with a timestampe as 1 and the other with null as 2.

If all the timestamps are nulls for the book_id and for the student_id - rate it as 1

the output should be like:

```
Student_id  Book_id class_id    timestamp   row_number
1101        NV5602  12          null        1
1101        NV5401  31  11/09/2021 16:50    1
1101        NV5401  12          null        2
```

[The desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITPMi.png)

Comment: Could you please post data as TEXT, not as pictures. Please read hiw to ask questions about [hive]: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hive/info

Comment: Removed [hql] tag. It is used for hybernate, not Apache Hive, use [hiveql] instead

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have changed it, I hope it is okay now

Comment: Much better! And what if all rows have timestamps and there are rows with same book_id?

Comment: This case could not happen as each book_id has a time on it (Book is borrowed) or no borrowed yet(null). So each book_id has only 2 options

Comment: Can it be rank more than 2 also: 3, 4, 5, ... if the same student has many books? Or only 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, it could be more than 2

Comment: Edited the answer, please check

Comment: Thanks, when I run it gives all 1 at the row_number – 1

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number. Demo:

```
with mydata as (
select 1101 Student_id, 'NV5602' Book_id,  12 class_id,  null timestamp_ union all
select 1101, 'NV5401',  31,  '11/09/2021 16:50' union all
select 1101, 'NV5401',  12,  null
)

select Student_id,  Book_id, class_id, timestamp_, 
       row_number() over(partition by student_id, case when timestamp_ is null then 1 else 0 end  order by regexp_extract(Book_id,'[A-Z]+(\\d+)$',1) desc) as row_number
from mydata
```

Result:

```
student_id  book_id class_id    timestamp_         row_number
1101        NV5401  31          11/09/2021 16:50    1
1101        NV5602  12          NULL                1
1101        NV5401  12          NULL                2
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run it gives all 1 at the row_number